# Is it possible to join two kerberos realms inside the same domain?

Tags: ldap, kerberos

In the current environment I am working with there are two LDAP directories, one is a Microsoft Active Directory and the other is a RedHat IDM LDAP Directory. Currently both kerberos realms exist inside the same domain (this was something that was set up in the past by someone else).

Normally we bind all our Linux VM's to IDM, and all our Windows VM's to AD, however we have started to build some Linux MSSQL VM's recently and our requirements have changed. The database administrators would like to use the AD MSSQL service accounts/SPN's.

Does anyone know if it possible to bind to both realms somehow even though they are part of the same domain?

I know the ideal solution would be to federate the directories, however that is not a possibility at the current moment.

Comment: One of them must be renamed.

Comment: This is what I thought, but I was hoping there might be a way I hadn't considered.